# Selenium send_keys doesn't sent apostrophe

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, sendkeys

In Selenium I want to input a teststring `"hello'world"`, but the webpage's textbox becomes `"helloworld"`. As if the apostrophe doesn't exist. Replacing `"'"` by `chr(39)` or splitsing the string doesn't do the job either.

- My part of the code: (using Chrome webdriver in python)

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://google.com")
text = "hello'world"
textbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//* 
[@id="tsf"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input')
for i in text:
    textbox.send_keys(i)
    sleep(0.1)
```

- Browser screenshot:
  [image: Browser screenshot]

Comment: Try with text = “hello”+”’”+ “World”. Sometime this issue appears because of keyboard layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**
Changed from Chromedriver to Firefox using geckodriver. The single and double quote seems to ge glitched in the current version of Chromedriver.

Answer (score 2):

To send the *character sequence* **hello'world** within the search box of *Google Home Page* you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use the following  [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  driver.get("https://google.com")
  text = "hello'world"
  textbox = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "q")))
  for i in text:
      textbox.send_keys(i)
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: apostrophe]

---

### Update

Seems previously there were some issues with the *non-US keyboard settings* and *Unicode characters* while invoking `send_keys()`. You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [SendKeys does not work correctly with non-US keyboard settings](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4523)
- [send_keys("é") to IE11  element sends e instead of é](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4518)
- [3.5.0 Grid - Selenium Keys / Unicode Failing](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4462)

This issue was solved through the commit [Fixing encoding of payload passed by hub to a node](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/9be6e6eacd15c44faf2c8704f73b662f84cdd31e).

Using *Selenium v3.5.3* should solve this issue.

---

### tl; dr

[Change your keyboard layout](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17424/windows-change-keyboard-layout)

Comment: Could you explain how the clickability of the element makes the difference between `helloworld` and `hello'world`?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski In short, _Google Search Home Page_ elements are [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element. Inducing _WebDriverWait_ for _element_to_be_clickable()_ we need to ensure that the element is _clickable_ i.e. all the _JavaScript_ and _AJAX Calls_ are completed, so the character sequence sent through `send_keys()` doesn't get distorted.

Comment: This doesn't seem to fix the problem, could it have to do with my keyboard layout? (azerty, Belgium) Although the '  seems to be the only character that doesn't get through.

Comment: @Cedric Good point, I need some time to check if any of the _keyboard layout_ have any impact on `send_keys()` method anyway.

Comment: @Cedric Checkout the answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: Changing my keyboard layout isn't really an option. The commit that presumably fixed the issue is for Java, but i'm using Python. "éèe" Is sent correctly, The only faulty character I found is ' and ".

Comment: @Cedric Possibly, you are right, I wish I could have reproduced the issue at my end to dig further. In-case of any positive development I will keep you updated.